# How to create a unique name when looping through each new category?

Tags: silverstripe

I need a way for each new category to have a unique name in a **data attribute**.

Below is how my code runs and displays:

E.g

---

**Category one**

*Picture 1 | Picture 2 | Picture 3*

**Category two**

*Picture 1 | Picture 2 | Picture 3 | Picture 4*

**Category three**

*Picture 1 | Picture 2*

---

What I need to do is when it starts a loop on each new category, every `<a>` in the `ServicePageSVTSliders` loop needs to add a `1` (or something similar) to `data-gall="myGallery">`. This way it will create a unique group for that category. And then when my lightbox pops up when the link is clicked it will just cycle through the particular images/iframes for that category instead of cycling through everything.

e.g

**Category one**

`data-gall="myGallery">` * 3 for Category one 
`data-gall="myGallery1">` * 4 for Category two 
`data-gall="myGallery2">` * 2 for Category three

**My Code:**

```
<% loop SVTCategorys %>
    <div class="svt-service-row">
        <div>
           <h2 class="svt-service-heading">$CategoryName</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
        <% loop ServicePageSVTSliders %>
          <a class="venobox_custom" 
         data-type="iframe" href="$SVTSliderLink" data-gall="myGallery">
           ... (Image sits in here)
         </a>
       <% end_loop %>
<% end_loop %>
```

Lightbox I am using: http://lab.veno.it/venobox/

Comment: So just thinking further I can use `$Up.CategoryName` as long as this is unique it will work.. But any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use $Pos which returns the position of the current loop.
If you need the position of the parent you can use $Up.Pos

```
<% loop SVTCategorys %>
<div class="svt-service-row">
    <div>
       <h2 class="svt-service-heading">$CategoryName</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
    <% loop ServicePageSVTSliders %>
      <a class="venobox_custom" 
     data-type="iframe" href="$SVTSliderLink" data-gall="myGallery$Up.Pos">
       ... (Image sits in here)
     </a>
   <% end_loop %>
<% end_loop %>
```

Comment: Nope, won't work as it needs to be the same name for each link in a category. Then when it gets to the new category, thats when a unique name needs to be created. The best solution I have come up with so far I have added as a comment to my original post.

Comment: Perfect, thats what I wanted. Thanks.